# How to initialize the PKCS11 provider without using SunPKCS11?

Tags: java, sunpkcs11

I have a problem and I tried searching a solution but couldn't find it. Someone please help me, thanks you so much.

```
String pkcs11Config = "name=CA-Token\nlibrary=C:/java/CA-Token_v2.dll\nslot=1";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes())
SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(is); // (1)
Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);
```

For this code, can we initialize the PKCS11 provider without using **SunPKCS11**?

Comment: Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but if you'd like to use a PKCS11 provider other than SunPKCS11, you can use:

- IAIK PKCS11 wrapper https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/products/core-crypto-toolkits/pkcs11-wrapper/
- OpenSC https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC-Java/blob/master/pkcs11-test/src/test/java/org/opensc/test/pkcs11/PKCS11ProviderTestCase.java
- Build your own provider by following Oracle tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/howtoimplaprovider.html#GUID-C485394F-08C9-4D35-A245-1B82CDDBC031

You just need to instantiate them and register with "Security.addProvider(yourProvider)"